# Multiple Category Design Changes

Tags: magento2

I want to changes 10 category design and keep ohter same how i can achieve this 0

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps,

- Go to the Magento admin panel and navigate to **Products > Categories**.
- Select the category you want to modify and go to the **Design tab**.
- In the **Custom Design** section, select **Custom** as the design and specify the layout and template files that you want to use for this category. You can also add any custom CSS or JavaScript in the **Layout Update XML** field.
- Save the category and repeat the process for the remaining categories that you want to modify.
- To keep the rest of the categories using the default design, leave the **Custom Design** field blank.